# How to get Dash in a column name of DataTable.Select in VB?

Tags: xml, vb.net

I got the XML data.

The XML data, e.g.

```
<person>
    <email-address>abc@test.com</email-address>
</person>
```

from my clsEmail.vb, e.g.

```
If XML.Tables("person").Select("email-address='" + Data Value + "'").Length = 1 Then
      Throw New Exception("Please enter another email address")
End If
```

BUT, the errors : Cannot find column [email].

Means that the dash can be other characters, which I tested:

```
XML.Tables("person").Select("email & Chr(150) &address....
```

is not working.

Is there any solution out there?

Comment: You can't use & "inside a string & expect it to concatenate it", Can you not simply call it my it's name `email-address` instead of concatenating it?

Comment: @OneFineDay nope that's not working as stated on my error that I received, " Cannot find column [email]. "

Comment: What datatype is the variable `XML`?

Comment: @JohnKoerner <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

Comment: `XML` looks like a dataset... am I right?

Comment: You should use an XML API like LINQ to XML to work with XML. That's especially true since you're using VB.NET which has very nice built-in support for it.

Comment: @JohnSaunders hey thanks but I just got my code right :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
If XML.Tables("person").Select("[email-address]='" + Data Value + "'").Length = 1 Then
    Throw New Exception("Please enter another email address")
End If
```

The `Select` of a datatable works just as a `SELECT` SQL statement; thus, when a column name contains a symbol or keyword, it should be written on brackets.

Comment: Yeap, that's the answer. Was about to write the answer myself already, but... here the tick.